# Why does a slightly delayed thread picks latest updated value of a static member variable of a class in a multi-thread java program?

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, jvm, static-members

I have been working on a below sample code:

```
public class GlobalStatic_Multithread extends Thread{

private static int threadcounter = 0;

public void run()
{
    threadcounter++ ;
    System.out.println(threadcounter);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i  =0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        new GlobalStatic_Multithread().start();
    }

    System.out.println(threadcounter +  " main ending");
}
```

}    
It is very clear three threads with each having it's own lock for the class **GlobalStatic_Multithread** will be started. My peers explanation for this program is, After Thread-1 starts the static variable ***threadcounter*** which is an int will be incremented to value 1. Before it get's printed there is every chance OS will preempts Thread-1 and runs Thread-2, it (Thread-2) will hold value 1 for ***threadcounter*** and it will increment to 2 and it gets printed (I mean Thread-2 will print) before Thread-1 prints value of ***threadcounter*** as 2. I am very clear on this theory and I clearly know the difference between static and non-static variables. 
There is some subtleness which I am not able to understand how these threads getting values for ***threadcounter***. My contention here is when Thread-1 started, it has it own local cache, so it should only look at it's own local cache unless the ***threadcounter*** is marked as volatile. When OS preempts Thread-1 just before it prints the value and let Thread-2 to run, Thread-2 incremented ***threadcounter*** to 2. How the Thread-1 got the value of ***threadcounter*** as 2 ? and Shouldn't Threads fetch values from their own cache? . Because, when OS preempts Thread-1, it is holding value of ***threadcounter*** as 1 in it's own cache and it should print ***threadcounter*** as 1. 
 I am missing something about JVM heap and threads local cache, hence I had to post this question. I know static member variables are associated with class and they have give constant value for all objects in a program (in other words if two objects of a class using static member variable ***int i=0*** and one object increments to ***i++*** then second object will get the updated value, which is 1 in this case). And I also knew the static member variables are stored in heap of JVM. 
And also I knew when JVM starts it loads each started thread with it's own copy of cache and that cache will hold all values of the class members.

Comment: Because static means there is only one member; and that's it.

Comment: Well the values in the cache have to be updated. And it is not necessary that the values are even cached. They can be read directly from the heap containing the shared variable.

Comment: @javaHunter...How a static variable that is updated by Thread-2 is seen or feteched by Thread-1. Each thread has it's own cache and when some thing happens to state of an object that will be updated in it's cache this is known fact in Java. When a Thread had to fetch a value of variable, it is fetching from it's cache (And this concept is well explained in concurrency). Yes, I do know it is fetching from HEAP. But I am not able to get my head around with the HEAP of a JVM and the local cache for each thread.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question?  What does this program actually output when _you_ run it in _your environment_?  What did you _expect_ it to output? and why did you expect it?

Comment: Just because the JLS _allows_ different threads to see different values of the same variable when they access it without synchronization does not mean that it actually will happen that way in any given JVM running on any given hardware.  Different hardware platforms have different _memory models_, some of which are more permissive than others.  The behavior that is _allowed_ by the JLS is allowed because it simplifies implementation of a JVM on the machines that have the most relaxed memory model.  The x86_64 archtitecure actually has a fairly tight memory model.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your coming from a different language and static means something different than what you're used to? Static in Java means there is only one property for the class, hence it is shared among the instances. Try running this to see if it makes more sense.

```
public class GlobalStatic_Multithread extends Thread{

private static int classCounter = 0;
private int instanceCounter = 0;

public void run()
{
    ++classCounter;
    ++instanceCounter;
    System.out.println("classCounter:" + classCounter + " instanceCounter:" + instanceCounter);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i  =0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        new GlobalStatic_Multithread().start();
    }

    System.out.println(threadcounter +  " main ending");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of flexibility in optimization that could be done by compiler and also hotspot native compilation, and you should not depend on any behavior that is not spec'd for the language.  If you are doing multithreaded programming, then you should program to get the express behavior you seek.

What you are doing right now is not threadsafe and will give undetermined results.

If you want increments to the static field to always take into consideration increments already made by both this and other threads, then you COULD use synchronization, but it would be better if you used one of the atomic classes:

```
public class GlobalStatic_Multithread extends Thread{

private static AtomicInteger threadcounter = new AtomicInteger(); // defaults to 0

public void run()
{
    int incrementedValue = threadcounter.incrementAndGet() ;
    System.out.println(incrementedValue);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i  =0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        new GlobalStatic_Multithread().start();
    }

    System.out.println(threadcounter.get() +  " main ending");
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to know that the 3 threads have finished their work before you get the value to print from main, then you should do something like this:

```
public class GlobalStatic_Multithread extends Thread {

private static AtomicInteger threadcounter = new AtomicInteger(); // defaults to 0
private CountDownLatch doneSignal;  // This will be passed to constructor instead of
                                    // static, to avoid race condition on construction
                                    // of object on main thread.

public GlobalStatic_Multithread(CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
    this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
}

public void run()
{
    int incrementedValue = threadcounter.incrementAndGet() ;
    System.out.println(incrementedValue);
    doneSignal.countDown();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int threadsToStart = 3;
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(threadsToStart );
    for(int i  =0 ; i < threadsToStart  ; i++)
    {
        new GlobalStatic_Multithread(latch).start();
    }

    latch.await(); // waits for all threads to finish (latch value goes to 0)
    System.out.println(threadcounter.get() +  " main ending");
}
```

Comment: S.Johnson... I understood and thanks for the example. And, There is reentrantreadwritelocks api too that helps me to get synchronised result by marking my static variable as atomicinteger. But that is not my contention.